# How to switch keys symbols on holding ALT?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, configuration

I wanna emulate numpad on letters uiojklm,.

I edited french layout in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` (see image below).
But I have to switch layout in order to use what I've done there.
I would like if for certain layout I could just hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

There is two options how I would like to switch to numbers:
-change to certain layout while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>;
-keys print different symbols while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>;
(or after activating <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: You need to be much more specific about what you need. Which keyboard layout are you using normally? Which symbols do you miss? Which file did you edit and exactly what changes did you make?

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson updated

Comment: Ok. Which layout are you normally using? To achieve what you want it's that layout you need to edit, i.e. you need to change the third symbol of respective key to a number. (OTOH, personally I would probably have created a custom layout for the purpose, and switched to it when inputting numbers.)

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson usually English(US), could you tell more about 3rd symbol...

Comment: Please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the English (US) keyboard layout like this:

```
$ diff /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us.orig /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us
26,28c26,28
<     key <AD07> {  [     u,    U       ]   };
<     key <AD08> {  [     i,    I       ]   };
<     key <AD09> {  [     o,    O       ]   };
---
>     key <AD07> {  [     u,    U, 7        ]   };
>     key <AD08> {  [     i,    I, 8        ]   };
>     key <AD09> {  [     o,    O, 9        ]   };
39,41c39,41
<     key <AC07> {  [     j,    J       ]   };
<     key <AC08> {  [     k,    K       ]   };
<     key <AC09> {  [     l,    L       ]   };
---
>     key <AC07> {  [     j,    J, 4        ]   };
>     key <AC08> {  [     k,    K, 5        ]   };
>     key <AC09> {  [     l,    L, 6        ]   };
51,53c51,53
<     key <AB07> {  [     m,    M       ]   };
<     key <AB08> {  [     comma,    less        ]   };
<     key <AB09> {  [    period,    greater     ]   };
---
>     key <AB07> {  [     m,    M, 1        ]   };
>     key <AB08> {  [     comma,    less, 2     ]   };
>     key <AB09> {  [    period,    greater, 3      ]   };
56a57,58
> 
>     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
```

That way I can type numbers like this:

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> -> 7

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> -> 5

etc.

The line

```
include "level3(ralt_switch)"
```

enables the third level mechanism; in this case <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> which is default for those keyboard layouts which make use of third and fourth level symbols, but it can be changed.

Comment: Could you take a look, please: https://askubuntu.com/q/1050584/393875

Comment: I holding ralt but nothing happens. Tried to reboot (should I reboot or log out ?).

Comment: @RS: You may have made a typo... I'd suggest that you edit your own question and show us what exactly your modified layout looks like. (Rebooting should not be necessary.)

Comment: Here is my us layout, I edited only 1 place - line 39. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R6VrOB0m3fxk8lE_RMXMCOsSvvCAsJVZ

Comment: @RS: You need to add the line `include "level3(ralt_switch)"` too.

Comment: I did, now it writes some strange symbol (�) when I switch to another layout and only in terminal, but in US still nothing. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qBLMYUPOGTk_E5dYssV8XHoo93xMICgn

Comment: @RS: That file works fine for me. <Right Alt>+J results in 4.

Comment: what could I do wrong ?