# How to make keys layout change key functions on Win key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, configuration

I want some keys to type numbers while I holding **left Win** key.
I need to edit 3rd column in layout (like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1043027/393875)).
There `include "level3(ralt_switch)"` stuff and no `lwin`.

Answer (score 0):

That ought to be the same as the answer of the other question you linked to, except that you should have

```
include "level3(lwin_switch)"
```

instead of

```
include "level3(ralt_switch)"
```

Comment: But should I just rewrite those line or add new block of configuration ?

Comment: @RS: Not sure what you mean. Assuming that it is the English (US) layout you want to edit, just use that line instead. If it is some other layout, my answer to the other question probably does not apply at all.